# vim-rails switch off autocompletion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

I use Tim Pope's [vim-rails](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails) and I would like to switch off the autocompletion (for example when I enter `AM.` it expands to `AcionMailer`). Don't want to change plugin itself, because I use git submodules for my plugins, rather I would like to switch off the completion within `vimrc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of that can be found just by reading the [fine documentation](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/blob/master/doc/rails.txt):

> ```
>   This variable was formerly used to globally disable abbreviations. Use
>   g:rails_no_abbreviations if you want to do that.
> ```

Therefore, putting

```
:let g:rails_no_abbreviations = 1
```

into your `~/.vimrc` should suffice.

You can also disable certain abbreviations via `:Rabbrev!`

> ```
>   ABBREVIATIONS *rails-abbreviations* *rails-snippets*
>
>   :Rabbrev! {abbr} Remove an abbreviation.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Vim-rails doesn't do autocompletion: the culprit is another plugin or custom function…

Without a link to your config, we won't be able to offer meaningful help.

Comment: Oooooh… "abbreviation". OK.